# THREE Js Rotate Mesh on Y axis to face specific vector position

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I've been spending most of the day trying to rotate a mesh on it's Y axis to face a specific Mesh location.

Found out some Methods but none helped me.

This is what I have.

```
   var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,5);
   var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
   turret.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(axis, vector.clone().normalize());
```

So I'm not sure I understeand why the turret wont rotate to face the specific `vector` position. I also tried this with Euler rotation by using `vec1.angleTo(vec2)` and rotate the turret to the specified direction but witouth success.

I would be really pleased if somebody can explain how this should work and what's the logic behind it if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `THREE.Vector3` constructor [(Docs)](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Math/Vector3):

```
Vector3( x, y, z )

x -- Float the vector's x value 
y -- Float the vector's y value 
z -- Float the vector's z value
```

You want to rotate a mesh on its Y axis, but you're actually rotating on its Z axis, so instead of:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 5);
```

try:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 5, 0);
```

Comment: Tried that too, without any result :(

Comment: Strange, that's working for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors... just seems like the mesh won't rotate at all on it's Y axis

Comment: For some reason as long as there is a 0 in the vector variable, the rotation wont occur

Comment: By default meshes are facing Y axis, so even if you set your vector (0, 100, 0), you won't see any rotation as it is already facing that direction. To see if it's working try (5,5,0). You should see some changes